# cv2.contourArea not working properly

Tags: python, image, opencv, contour, area

What I'm trying to do is find big light polluted areas in a photo of nighttime Earth. I converted the source photo to grayscale and then to binary photo with a threshold. cv2.findcontours works properly but when I try to get rid of small contours it only deletes a part of them.

[Source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3MTn.jpg)

```
import cv2
image_orig=cv2.imread('C:\Users\pc\Desktop\middleeast.jpg')
image_gray=cv2.cvtColor(image_orig,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, image_threshold=cv2.threshold(image_gray,60,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_,contours,_=cv2.findContours(image_threshold,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
image_contours=image_orig.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image_contours,contours,-1,(255,255,0),1)
cv2.imshow('image_contours',image_contours)
cv2.imwrite('C:\Users\pc\Desktop\middleEastAllContours.jpg', image_contours)
for counter,contour in enumerate(contours):
    if cv2.contourArea(contour)<250.0:
        contours.pop(counter)
image_big_contours=image_orig.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image_big_contours,contours,-1,(255,255,0),1)
cv2.imshow('big contours',image_big_contours)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

As you can see there still are plenty of small light polluted areas contoured. How can I get rid of them?

[All contours comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF91v.jpg)

[Big contours comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAAJt.jpg)

[Source image all contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTzHy.jpg) [Source image big contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QU7w.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the pop of the for: when you pop a contour, you are skipping the next one.

For example, if you pop contour number 10, then the next countour will become number 10, but you will skip it because in the next iteration you will look at contour 11.

I am not a python expert (I don't really know how the two variables are used in the for) but you could try to do a counter=counter-1 after the pop. Another option is iterate the list backwards (start in the last element and finish at the first)